# Cordova onsen app.Google map is working in desktop but not working in android nd ios app

Tags: cordova, angular, google-maps-sdk-ios, onsen-ui2

I am new to onsen2 and angular2. Now, I am developing hybrid app. I tried to implement angular2 google map which is working fine in desktop but not working in android and ios with error(Google is not defined). The code what, I used is shown below. Solutions are welcome.

***app.component.html***

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

***app.component.ts***

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {OnsNavigator} from 'angular2-onsenui';

declare var $:any;
declare var google: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'ons-page[page]',
  template: require('./page.html'),
  styles: [require('./page.css')]
})
export class Page {
  constructor(private navi : OnsNavigator) {
   }

  push() {
    this.navi.element.pushPage(Page);
  }

ngOnInit() {

  // initialize google map
  var myLatLng = {lat: 12.8767, lng: 80.2302};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'ZSL Inc, 85 Lincoln Highway, Edison, NJ 08820'
  });


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error says, google is not defined. When using Cordova you need to keep in mind that the browser support may be different for each platform (even for every Android version, I recommend using Crosswalk for Android), so it might not have a global google variable defined

The solution is to use a plugin for mobile devices (like [this](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps))
If you want to keep support for the PC browser just test the each variable before loading, like:

```
If(window.google && window.google.maps){
// Current code
}
else if(plugin.google && plugin.google.maps){
// check the link above
}
```